# Jasper Reports - check if table is empty (no records) and hide table label

Tags: jasper-reports, is-empty

My scenario: 2 tables on Summary field, each table has its own dataset. Also, each table is labelled so there is a label just on top each table.All is ok, however if there is no data in table, table is not printed but table label is still visible.

I need to hide table label if table has no data. Is it even possible? I can't find any solution how to determine if table is empty or not, to set is as expression that will hide label.

Any ideas?

Comment: What kind of datasource are you passing to the table component?, can you include relevant jrxml of how you call the the table component

Comment: you can put any table in a subreport  and uses properties like whenNoDataType NoPages, BlankPage for example. maybe you also can control in a band.

Comment: Is there any way to print table if no data in table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem to get the record count from your table component this is done by returning value

```xml
<returnValue fromVariable="REPORT_COUNT" toVariable="TABLE_COUNT"/>
```

However this will **not solve** you problem since you can not set the `evalutationTime` of the `printWhenExpression`, you can only set `evalutationTime` of the `textFieldExpression`

The problem is normally solved by **moving** your "table label" where it is expected to be, in the **table header**

From IDE group your columns and add the `textField` in the `groupHeader` inside the table header.

**Example** (jrxml result)

```xml
<componentElement>
    <reportElement key="table" style="table" x="0" y="33" width="360" height="50" uuid="6a7d5ab9-f15d-4676-85b2-1e48f016c155"/>
    <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
        <datasetRun subDataset="tableData" uuid="fa5df3de-f4c5-4bfc-8274-bd064e8b81e6">
            <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
        </datasetRun>
        <jr:columnGroup width="217" uuid="c96f6ab0-8cce-4dc7-b686-da6928e7cabb">
            <jr:tableHeader height="61" rowSpan="1">
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="217" height="61" uuid="98aa260d-7e84-4df7-89cc-fc1eabdcf656"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["MY TABLE LABEL"]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </jr:tableHeader>
            <jr:column width="90" uuid="889a828a-ad48-40a0-81f4-326a95d6585c">
                <jr:columnHeader style="table_CH" height="60" rowSpan="1"/>
                <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="43" rowSpan="1">
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="43" uuid="82b2a835-4373-4638-b75a-d43f531678ba"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{myField1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </jr:detailCell>
            </jr:column>
            <jr:column width="127" uuid="004c3afe-c39f-44e2-a82d-5c96697ebd7e">
                <jr:columnHeader style="table_CH" height="60" rowSpan="1"/>
                <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="43" rowSpan="1">
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="43" uuid="90287319-765f-49a0-9f80-0851f40f2b13"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{myField2}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </jr:detailCell>
            </jr:column>
        </jr:columnGroup>
    </jr:table>
</componentElement>
```

Comment: Yes, your idea is probably the best possible. I managed to do the same by myself.